# How to get data of all users except current login user from cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a users collection where i stored usernames of all users, now i want to get usernames of users except current login user. can someone help ?

here is how i get usernames of all users :

```
class ChatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
_ChatsScreenState createState() => _ChatsScreenState();
}

class _ChatsScreenState extends State<ChatsScreen> {
User currentUser;

@override
void initState() {
currentUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .orderBy('addedOn', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshots) {
      if (!snapshots.hasData) {
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = snapshots.data.docs[index];
            return Text(document.data()['username']);
          });
    });
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you don't want to show the current username on the list you display by ListView widget.

```
return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = snapshots.data.docs[index];
            return Text(document.data()['username']);
          });
```

before print the Text widget here use if else statement

if the document.data()['username'] == currentUser.username

(I don't remember the parameter when get data from firebase also you can create a custom user class to take the parameters you need) don't return the Text widget else return the Text widget

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to do it in firebase yet, although firebase added the `!=`  query this month officially, not sure when it is coming to the FlutterFire repository.

So as a workaround, you'll have to compare the current logged in user's `uid` and then show the usernames that don't match it.

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.data.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = snapshots.data.docs[index];

                if(document.id == auth.currentUser.uid){
                  return Container(height:0);
                }

            return Text(document.data()['username']);
          });
    });
```

You can directly query for all the username's that are not equal to the current logged in user's uid once the firestore plugin is updated. So keep a lookout for FlutterFire repo.